# Play music from listboxes in new tabs created through tabcontrol?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-media-player

Here is the add playlist code in C#

```
//toolstrip button to create new playlist
private void newPlaylistToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //CreatePlaylist();

    TabPage tab = new TabPage($"Playlist {tabControl1.TabPages.Count}");
    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tab);

    ListBox listbox22 = new ListBox();
    listbox22.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    listbox22.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

    tab.Controls.Add(listbox22);

}
```

Here is play button code:

```
private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    double pausedPosition = WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;
    WMPPlayer.URL = filepaths[listBox1.SelectedIndex];
    WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = pausedPosition;
    WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

ADDING MUSIC TO TABS CODE:

```
private void addToPlaylistToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>()
            .FirstOrDefault(page => page.Text == tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text)
            ?.Controls.Cast<Control>()
            .FirstOrDefault(control => control is ListBox) as ListBox)?.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);

        listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
        ListBox current_listbox = (ListBox)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0];
    }
```

When we reference listbox1 in the play button code, that is the main listbox in the middle of the screen before you make any new tabs. This is a music player and the new tabs are playlists that users can add music to. When I try to play a song through the new tab, nothing plays. How can I make the play button play songs in these newly formed tabs/listboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the active controls yourself.  Since it looks like your TabPages only have one control on them, you can simply access the first control in the Controls collection:

```
private void Play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ListBox lb = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as ListBox;
  if (lb != null && lb.SelectedIndex > -1) {
    double pausedPosition = WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;
    WMPPlayer.URL = filepaths[lb.SelectedIndex];
    WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = pausedPosition;
    WMPPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
  }
}
```

If there are multiple controls on your TabPages, then you can loop through your controls and look for a ListBox type or give your controls a specific name that you can use as a key.

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. tabpage does not have a definition for "Control", there is an expected ";" for As, and Listbox is never used. All the errors are in that first line before the "if" you added

Comment: It's still only playing whatever is highlighted in the main listbox. Is there a way to clear all selected index in other tabs besides whatever tab is currently open?

Comment: @BenjaminBraddock Your filepaths variable makes no sense, since you are referencing it by index.  Each tab needs its own filepaths list.  You didn't post any code regarding how you are supplying the ListBox collection.

Comment: edited the question to contain the create listbox through tab code

Comment: @BenjaminBraddock You already had that code posted.  Per the code you posted, the ListBox is empty.

Comment: sorry, very early. maybe this is the code you want to see? edited above

Comment: @BenjaminBraddock Not sure why you would move anything.  Every tab should have it's own list.  My guess is that you should probably make a class called MusicFile or something, with a Title, Artist, and FullPath properties.  Override the ToString to return the Title, and just add that to each ListBox.  When you click on the Play button, you can then cast the selected item to the MusicFile class and get access to the FullPath property, and update your media player that way.  Would be much cleaner and easier to maintain approach.

Comment: i have about 40 minutes. did you see the other code? i'm dying here

Comment: @BenjaminBraddock Your file information is coming from your filepaths array.  That really is your problem there.